# RSolveValue, Table and general programming

Tags: programming, list-manipulation, procedural-programming

If I have the  following code:

```
 temperature[q_] := RSolveValue[{b[n] == b[n - 1] - time, b[0] == 90}, b, n]; Table[{time, temperature[1000][Range[0, 3]]}, {time, {2, 3, 5}}]
```

where the output results in the the first element of time being subtracted by all all elements of `temperature[1000][Range[0, 3]]`. The output is: {{2, {90, 88, 86, 84}}, {3, {90, 87, 84, 81}}, {5, {90, 85, 80, 75}}}.

How can I modify the code such as the subtraction is the first element of time being subtracted by the first element of `temperature[1000][Range[0, 3]]` and then the second element of time being subtracted by `temperature[1000][Range[0, 3]]` and so on as to give an output such: `{90, 88, 85, 80}}`

PS:This question is an extension of another question asked here [General question about RSolveValue and general programming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220624/general-question-about-rsolvevalue-and-general-programming)

Comment: What's the purpose of the argument `q` of `temperature`? It appears nowhere else.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut for this particular example there is no purpose for q. I removed that part from the code to make it simpler and focus only on the part of time. But you are right, if I put for example ‘q*time’ then time would be multiplied by 1000

Comment: The problem here is that you are computing the solution of a recurrence relation where `time` is a constant, which yields a function `n->90-n*time`, and then you want to make `time` a variable. It won't work. Why rely on `RSolveValue`?
You may use `Accumulate`, for instance: `90 - Prepend[Accumulate[#], 0]&`

Comment: Hi @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, could you expand a little bit on how to use accumulate for time?. Where do I put the list of the variable time in this code?. Thanks

Comment: As an argument. It's a function... Do you prefer `f[time_]:=90-Prepend[Accumulate[time],0]`?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut what I don't understand is how to get the output I want with this function. The output I want is: `{90, 88, 85, 80}` but with the function I keep getting the same using: `f[time_] := 90 - Prepend[Accumulate[time], 0]
Table[{time, temperature[1000][Range[0, 3]]}, {time, {2, 3, 5}}]` . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What I think is that the problem is really in the way the function is called. when using `Table[{time, temperature[1000][Range[0, 3]]}, {time, {2, 3, 5}}]` in which I get `{{2, {90, 88, 86, 84}}, {3, {90, 87, 84, 81}}, {5, {90, 85, 80, 75}}}`. But a modification of this part should be able to give me `{90, 88, 85, 80}`

Comment: `f[time_] := 90 - Prepend[Accumulate[time], 0]; f[{2, 3, 5}]` yields `{90, 88, 85, 80}`. Or `(90 - Prepend[Accumulate[#], 0] &)[{2, 3, 5}]` yields the same.